# Restoring a numpy array representing an image after base64 encoding

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, base64

Using base64 encoding on images gives the opportunity to fully restore the image to its original shape, with all its dimension (2D, RGB) without knowing the resolutions directly - they are stored inside the base64 information

However, when I have a numpy array representing an image like:

```
test_image = np.random.rand(10,10,3)
```

and then put it into base64 with:

```
b64_test_image = base64.b64encode(test_image)
```

I am able to get back to the content of the array with:

```
decoded = base64.b64decode(b64_test_image)
test_image_1D = np.frombuffer(decoded)
```

However, `test_image_1D` is only one-dimensional in comparison to the orignal image which had the dimension `10x10x3`. Is it possible to restore the orignal array without knowing the buffer size, like it is the case with images?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your data is always an image, you need to use a library to get the image back from the base64 encoded string. For example with OpenCV:

```
retval, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', test_image)
jpg_as_text = base64.b64encode(buffer)
nparr = np.fromstring(base64.b64decode(jpg_as_text), np.uint8)
img2 = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

Comment: LookupError: 'base64' is not a text encoding; use codecs.decode() to handle arbitrary codecs , comes from the first line of code. If it is swapped to base64.b64encode(b64_test_image) - img will be empty

Comment: I edited the answer and now it should work. It does for me with Python 3.6

Comment: After trying for 30 hours, I came to your answer and .... THANK YOU